# Javascript array get all child values without knowing the parent key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to validate and check if there is any existing object with true value where I don't know how to directly access all child exist value without having me to loop through the parent array. Below show the result.

```
{
 user1: Array(2)
  0: {exist: false}
  1: {exist: true}
 user2: Array(2)
  0: {exist: false}
  1: {exist: false}
}
```

Comment: I will help people understand your javascript question if you make your code actual javascript. I have no idea why an array has a `[user1]` or `[exist]` key. Is it really an array or an object? Just use javascript that someone trying to help you will be able to execute and easily understand where you are starting from.

Comment: Please also show an example of the source data that gives this result

Comment: I am doing event session date time checking to validate each attendee's new schedule with their existing one to avoid clashes whereby i perform for looping each attendee with an inner loop of the session datetime then check it in my db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the object will only be this deep, you can use `some` on `Object.values()`. You are still looping through the arrays — there's no way to avoid that — but at least it's fairly succinct:

```js
let obj = {
  user1:[
   {exist: false},
   {exist: false}
  ],
  user2: [
   {exist: false},
   {exist: true}
  ]
 }
 
let t = Object.values(obj).some(arr => arr.some(o => o.exist === true))
// are some objects true?
console.log(t)
```

If your objects can be arbitrarily deep, you will need to recursively look at everything.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot. You either query parent key, then child key, or you loop all the parent keys, then child keys.